# How to repair bowed sliding door frame?

Tags: door-frame, sliding-glass-door

It’s tough to see from the picture, but the entire top section of frame of the sliding door is bowed downward.

I’ve tried adjustments on the door, and it either gets stuck in the middle or falls off track on the ends.

**Any ideas on how to repair?**

*I’d be happy to edit in any clarifying information.*

[image]

Comment: Is it just the screen panel that slides? The door itself looks like a hinged door. If it is the screen, those things are difficult at best to get right, any one teensy thing will make them stick or jump track. A few pics of the door head in question would help see the issue better.

Comment: Wow that is impressively bad.  Is the frame visibly untrue on the inside as well?

Comment: @Jack the inside of the door is a regular swing door. The outside slider screen is the problem.

Comment: @KH inside the door is fine. From this view the ‘door’ on the right is a false door. It only seems to be the exterior frame for the sliding track

Comment: Usually the rollers, *top and bottom*, on the screen door are height adjustable. Possibly there may be enough of an adjustment to lower the door enough to operate correctly.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I’ve fiddled with the rollers beyond the limits of what’s reasonable. The height difference between the middle and ends of the track or simply too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without replacing any materials, or doing any construction, I found this simple fix. While not elegant, it serves the purpose for only a few bucks. I actually had these washers in hand already, so it actually cost $Free.99!

[image]
[image]

Comment: While I presume that this has gotten your screen door to slide (and thanks for posting your answer!), I would encourage you to look into why it appears that the framing around the door is sagging. From your OP pic, it looks as though a straight edge across the trim at the top of the door would A) not be level and B) leave a gap in the middle of the door. If it's just the trim/door unit sagging, that's not _too_ worrying, but if there's an actual issue with the structural header above the door unit, that could be a major concern.

Comment: @FreeMan completely agree

Comment: Yes, you need to eventually fix this right. There could be water damage  that you don't even know about.

Answer (score 3):

From you post it appears that the French doors are OK but the problem is with the sliding screen door.  I'd get a 6.5' 2x4  and my car jack and try to lift up at the middle of the frame to see if it's just separated from the header or if you have a structural problem. If it can be lifted into position, refasten it with some long wood screws through the frame and into the header. If it can't be lifted then you have a more serious problem and you'll have to remove some siding to investigate further and report back here.